# Square-free values of polynomials of degree 3

Tags: number-theory, abc-conjecture

While reading an article by Dan Carmon on *Square-free values of large polynomials over the rational function field*, I tried to prove that square-free polynomials of degree $1$ and $2$ have a positive density. This I was able to do with some help of the article *Squarefree values of quadratic polynomials* by Zeev Rudnick

**My quesion**
Why doesn't this strategy work for polynomials of degree $3$ and why do we need the ABC-conjecture here, i.e., why can't we use the Sieve of Eratosthenes for polynomials of degree 3? I suppose it has something to do with the fact that when looking at polynomials of degree $1$, multiples of primes are evenly spaced. Any thoughts?

Comment: What do you mean with density in this context ? Do you look at all values of polynomials with integer coefficients at some integer ? In the body you speak of "square-free polynomials" in one sentence which does not seem to be the intent of the question.

Comment: The density $c_f = \prod_p \left(1-\frac{\rho_f(p^2)}{p^2}\right).$ And $\rho_f(k) = \#\{a \bmod k: f(a) \equiv 0 \bmod k\}.$ When I speak of square-free polynomials, I mean polynomials that do obtain square-free values and have a positive density. For instance, the polynomial $f(x) = x^2$ is only square free for $x = 0$ and $1$, and therefore has an asymptotic density of $0$.

Comment: For cubic polynomials it's harder due to "large" primes p with $p^2$ dividing f(n). However you don't need abc. I think this is in Hooley's book "Applications of Sieve Methods to the Theory of Numbers".

Comment: @Pasten But why then is it harder? And why is this not a problem for quadratic polynomials?

Comment: As I said: due to "large" primes p with $p^2$ dividing f(n). In the quadratic case when $p^2$ divides f(n) then p can be at most of size O(n). In the cubic case instead, p can be considerably larger than n. If you work out by hand your proof in the quadratic case and try to make it work in the cubic case, here is precisely where things will fail.